# Equivalent of jQuery code in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the following lines of code in JavaScript but they are in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

How can I do the above in Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ is a good place to start

Comment: .closest is released in vanilla JS but is not widely supported cross-browser. A work-around is to place the js inline in your HTML elements. This works nicely.

Comment: @RonRoyston It actually has great support as long as you don't need IE11 ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest))

Answer (score 0):

`closest` will work on mos browsers other than IE (Edge supports it though). For IE, you can define a prototype as following:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) 
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
if (!Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest = function (selector) {
        var el = this;
        while (el) {
            if (el.matches(selector)) {
                return el;
            }
            el = el.parentElement;
        }
    };
}
```

Now, you can use the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('focus',function(e){
    if ((e.target).closest("tbody").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}, true);
```